# Practical implementation of SSAS(Step by step)

Tags: ssas

I am a novice in SSAS with some theoretical knowledge in it.

I would like to do the very first and the simplest of all implementation in that.

I searched in Google but the one's I found are a bit high enough for me to grasp.

Could you please suggest me some good links/articles(Step by Step [ would be better if diagrams are given]) to start with.

I mean no inbuit AdventureWorks SSAS db.  I like to say not the examples given in `Microsoft Press book entitled SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services Step By Step (0735621993)`. Though it is good and basically helps to learn but I fell (after completing first 3 chapters) that there I need to install some already given DW's which I am not looking for

Everything should be from scratch so that I will learn properly though it may take a bit time.

Also it would be of great help to me and also for peoples like me  if someone can tell direct the sequential steps to follow from start to end (like create dimensions, measures then cube etc. ) for creating a SSAS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some step by step articles here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thanks for the answer. But apart from Microsoft, because they use their own SSAS Advantureworks DW for the explanation . What i need is from the DW degisn till the implementation ; I mean entirely new from the scratch

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Applied Microsoft Analysis Services 2005](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976635305) and [Practical Business Intelligence with SQL Server 2005](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356985)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101242/nice-book-on-sql-server-analysis-services) for more info.